# Как сделать, чтобы mysql смотрел наружу?

Tags: mysql

Как сделать, чтобы mysql (ubuntu linux) смотрел наружу и к нему можно было подключиться внешней программой?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, к mysql и так можно подключиться, если знаешь хост и порт, для этого ничего делать и не нужно...

Comment: Он на другом сервере установлен

Comment: ну и если вы знаете адрес этого сервера и у вас есть к нему доступ, то ничего не меняется...

Comment: не могу подключиться

Comment: добавьте больше подробностей в сообщение: какие действия вы проводите для подключения, какую ошибку вы получаете и т.д.

Comment: Указываю адрес, имя, пароль... подключаюсь... выдаёт ошибку 10061

Comment: читаю тут http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/mysql "По умолчанию сервер MySQL принимает соединения только с локальной машины."

Answer (score 1):

найдите конфигурационный файл *mysqld*, содержащий директиву `bind-address`:

```
$ grep -rl bind-address /etc/mysql
```

скорее всего, она содержит адрес `127.0.0.1`:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

чтобы *mysqld* слушал не только этот адрес, но и любой адрес на всех сетевых интерфейсах, [замените `127.0.0.1` на `*`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address), чтобы директива выглядела так:

```
bind-address = *
```

и перезапустите *mysqld*:

```
$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

> В MySQL пользователь характеризуется двумя параметрами: именем и
>   хостом, с которого он может обращаться. По умолчанию доступ разрешен
>   только с локальной машины, т.е. для пользователя user@localhost.  Права на доступ пользователям даются с помощью команды GRANT.

Подробней: [Настройка удаленного подключения к MySQL](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/11.html)